# code - h10- heroku after after deploying app

Tags: python

***I have deployed fast API and selenium python script to Heroku. I have added the required buildpacks and config variable before deploying and tried everything but still, I get the error. The script runs perfectly on the local host, but I can't seem to run it on the Heroku server. Below are the image of log details and my code on Github. I really appreciate the help***

[ss of build logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEz2M.png)
https://github.com/sus0001/kalimati_market-fastAPI

Comment: How do you start your app locally? Your `Procfile` states `python main.py` but I see no actual startup code there.

Comment: I start by typing "uvicorn main:app --reload" and it runs perfectly fine on my local server. What else do I need to add on the Procfile, as per the instructions found on YouTube and Google, I only see this line in Procfile before deploying the app.

Comment: What you put in the Procfile is the commando used to start the app, so try putting `uvicorn main:app` there (no need for restart in production)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for helping out, adding this **web: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app** to my Procfile resolve my issue.